# Save a `toDataURL` Image to Server

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, todataurl

I've tried implementing [signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad), but I honestly don't understand it.

How do I return an image value and post it to my server?

EDIT:

I've tried decoding:

JavaScript "app.js":

```
saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
        alert("Please provide signature first.");
    } else {
        saveSignature(signaturePad.toDataURL());
    }
});

function saveSignature(dataURL) {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "script.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: dataURL
  }
}).done(function(o) {
  console.log('saved'); 
});
}
```

PHP, "script.php":

```
<?php
    // requires php5
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP code you must get `$_POST['imgBase64']` instead of `$_POST['img']`.

> your PHP code dosen't return `json` data

try this:
`echo json_encode(['result' => $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.'])`

Comment: Thank-you. I did some more reading and realised that. Will your solution work, or should I use the solution I tried in my edited OP? The attempt I made in my edited OP doesn't work, but I think it's close to working.

Comment: in `$.ajax` call add `dataType: "json"` to be sure about data type and do as my answer in PHP code

Comment: [Here's an image of my web directory](http://i.imgur.com/kiZblB8.png). I tried your fixes, and I'm still not getting any return. Should I be doing some other things, too?

Comment: I don't know how to get a console up. I use Coda, mostly, an app that just lets you edit the files. I tried opening the whole site in DreamWeaver, but don't know how to get a console for that either. Sorry.

Comment: @yeeeeee in chrome you can `Right-click` and click `Inspect` item.And choose `Console` tab.(CTRL+SHIFT+I [In windows])

Comment: [Can't find variable `$`](http://i.imgur.com/I9UDljF.png).  If I delete the `$`, it says it can't find variable ajax.

Comment: I imported the relevant script for ajax, so that's working now, but now I have an internal server error "500". It seems to be related to the PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146936/discussion-between-yashar-aliabasi-and-yeeeeee).